# geometry of a hyperbola and circle drawn together

Tags: analytic-geometry

how to calculate the radius of a circle which is drawn below(inwards) the hyperbola curve touching it.need a relationship between these hyperbola and circle .If a circular object is place below the hyperbola touching it how to calculate the radius of the circular object.

Comment: In what form is the hyperbola? If is pole is at $0$ and its abscissa ($\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$) is $0$ you need to find a point where $\pmatrix{1\\f'(x)}$ is orthogonal to $\pmatrix{x\\f(x)}$. This point will be on the circle and the center will be $\pmatrix{0\\0}$.